# How to use Ember.js without using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm very interested in using ember.js for one of my applications.  I'm tired of spaghetti javascript/jquery.  I understand I'm not bound to using Handlebars but how are you supposed to to use emberjs without it?  Also, are there major drawbacks to *not* using Handlebars with emberjs?  I haven't found any resources on the web on how to work with emberjs without it.

Comment: According to the docs, you can use Ember with another templating library but you won't get data binding. Personally that's a large portion of why I'm using Ember so that's not a trade-off I'm willing to make.

Answer (score 0):

Ember.js is very powerful even if you never touch Handlebars. Between the object model, property/observer/binding system, state managers, and javascript views, you can do a lot. If you do want to use a templating system, I would recommend using Handlebars so you can take advantage of data-binding. However, it's pretty trivial to use a different templating system if there's another one that really floats your boat.

Comment: This answer indicates that it *can* be done, but does not indicate how. I do not think that's what the original author was asking

Comment: You can register JS functions in Ember.TEMPLATES with the expected names. They can be any function that accepts an optional context parameter and returns a string of HTML that will be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: To be clear, I would not recommend this approach -- the data binding support in Ember Handlebars is too powerful to want to give up. But understanding the architecture is helpful, and, over time, there will be people ambitious enough to create databinding-capable alternatives to Handlebars for Ember.

Comment: When you do SVG, the templating system is quite useless inside the view system (because jquery doesn't support namespaces and animation, you can't even bind a className). But you still might want to use the observer/binding system, and the Ember.run for async core is intrusive too. So you might end up with a library that depends on Ember without actually wanting the templates.